# Python 3 : print float precision without zero followed

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point

For example

```
x = 1.23
print("%.3f" % x)
```

Output will be "1.230" and I want "1.23".
Is there any way to do? Thank you.

edited:
I want a function that will print floating point at **limit precision** and will not print zero followed if it's not reach the limit given

Comment: Edited. Sorry for being not clear. @DeepSpace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to output up-to 3 digits but without 0 you need to format to 3 digit and `rstrip` zeros:

```
for n in [1.23,1.234,1.1,1.7846]:
    print('{:.3f}'.format(n).rstrip("0"))  # add .rstrip(".") to remove the . for 3.00003
```

Output:

```
1.23
1.234
1.1
1.785
```

Have a quick read here for python 3 formattings:  https://pyformat.info/#number or here: https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#format-examples